# rails undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass with belongs to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :props
end
```

This is my prop model ( porp is short from property)

```
class Prop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

I have this problem.
When I create prop I require item_id. 
But if there is no item with this id
I will get an error here:

```
<%= @prop.item.id %>

    <%= @prop.item.name %>
```

What do I do?

UPD:I can check its existence like `<%= @prop.item.try(:name) %>`  What are my other options?

Comment: Your Item model has` has_many :items` Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh it seems to be noot a typo I entered it manually so It's a mistake!

Comment: I changed it to has_many :props the problem still exist

Comment: Do you have any validations in Prop model?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use NullObject.

```
class Item
  def self.null
    Item.new(name: 'null')
  end
end

@item = @prop.item || Item.null
```

Then this code will not raise error:

```
<%= @item.id %>

<%= @item.name %>
```